# Win10: VS Code integrated bash not loading ~/.bash_profile

Tags: .bash-profile, visual-studio-code

As the title suggest, when I start my git bash regularly it loads my ~/.bash_profile but the one integrated in my VS Code is not loading it.

Where can I put .bash_profile so that it would also load in VS Code?

Edit: here's my vs code with the terminal
[image: vs code]

and here's my git bash [image: git bash]

I want to load the same .bash_profile file in my vs code terminal that is loading on my git bash, so that it would show the branch name and also have aliases i defined there.

Comment: What file are you talking about?

Comment: my .bash_profile that is currently at ~/.bash_prifile

Comment: Are you asking how to integrate your git bash profile with Visual Studio?

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out, that it had to do in how the terminal is started. The git bash one (in its own window) is using the login to start and hence reads `.bash_profile`.

The one in vs code is started not in the login way (sorry, I'm not well versed in this), and reads `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`.

My solution was to move all the stuff I kept in `.bash_profile` and move it to `.bashrc` and add the following line to `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

which loads the `.bashrc` contents when starting in the login way.

Comment: git bash for windows does the same thing with a similar syntax `test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding to the settings: `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-l"],`

---

As an alternative you can use the `.bashrc` file instead of `.bash_profile`.

Comment: VS Code says this now:
This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.linux#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux#`.
See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

Answer (score 2):

Using WSL (Ubuntu 16.04), I had to add the following option to my settings.json in VS Code in order to run the shell as a login shell:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To everybody suggesting using `.bashrc` as a replacement for `.bash_profile`, it's important to distinguish between the two, as they are different:

- `.bash_profile` is executed at login.
- `.bashrc` is executed each time a `bash` instance is created, *including sub-shells*.

Using `.bashrc` for such settings might cause errors and even be dangerous. For instance, this kind of code is usually added to `.bash_profile` and should never be added to `.bashrc`:

```bsh
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

(The `HOME` variable could have been altered, plus `$HOME/bin` will be added multiple times).

Also, aliases are defined in `.bashrc` (like `alias rm='/usr/bin/rm -i'`) and are only meant to be used in interactive shells, so scripts using `rm` or `cp` will break.

The right answer for this question, as others suggested, is adding:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        }
     }
}
```

The local file can be found here:

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

That will make shell scripts started from VSCode to run the `.bash_profile` script, but not the subshells.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to the accepted answer:

**In your root directory add a file .bashrc with the following code:**

```
source <rootdirectory>/.bash_profile
```

Where you replace  with your own root.

For example that could be *C:/Users/domkj/.bash_profile*

Answer (score 0):

I created .bashrc in home path and importing that other profiles
`test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Windows/WSL users, in the VSCode `settings.json` file I added `"-l"` to the `"args"` property which is now listed under `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux/bash`:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        }
```

The local file can be found here:

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`